# Displaying a dictionary in a tree structure in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to display it in a specific format.

This is my dictionary:

```
tree = {
  'wesley': {
    '1': {
      'romulan': {
        '1': '0',
        '0': '1'
      }
    },
    '0': {
      'romulan': {
        '1': '0',
        '0': {
          'poetry': {
            '1': {
              'honor': {
                '1': '0',
                '0': '1'
              }
            },
            '0': {
              'honor': {
                '1': '1',
                '0': '0'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display it as:

```
wesley = 1 :
| romulan = 1 : 0
| romulan = 0 : 1
wesley = 0 :
| romulan = 1 : 0
| romulan = 0 :
| | poetry = 1 :
| | | honor = 1 : 0
| | | honor = 0 : 1
| | poetry = 0:
| | | honor = 1 : 1
| | | honor = 0 : 0
```

I am very new to dictionaries and Python and I have no knowledge of how to display them.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I've never seen a standard output format matching what you want. You're going to have to roll your own code to do this; doing it properly would probably involve a recursive function. If you're this new to Python, I would not start with something like this; `pprint.pprint` is usually good enough for basic inspection, and you need to learn the basics before you dive into more complicated subjects. This is an incredibly specific problem, the code you write is mostly useless for other purposes, and it involves several concepts you're probably unfamiliar with.

Comment: I was afraid of this, thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you need it this way? you've got some strange data structuring with string-based numerical indexes...couldn't you just use a list for those?  `{wesley: [{...}, {...}, {...}] }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get it pretty close without recursion, though it's potentially brittle

```
import json

tree = {'wesley': {'1': {'romulan': {'1': '0', '0': '1'}}, '0':    {'romulan': {'1': '0', '0': {'poetry': {'1': {'honor': {'1': '0', '0': '1'}}, '0': {'honor': {'1': '1', '0': '0'}}}}}}}}


tree_str = json.dumps(tree, indent=4)
tree_str = tree_str.replace("\n    ", "\n")
tree_str = tree_str.replace('"', "")
tree_str = tree_str.replace(',', "")
tree_str = tree_str.replace("{", "")
tree_str = tree_str.replace("}", "")
tree_str = tree_str.replace("    ", " | ")
tree_str = tree_str.replace("  ", " ")

print(tree_str)
```

Output:

```
    (.venv35) ➜  stackoverflow python weird_formated_print.py

wesley:
 | 0:
 | | romulan:
 | | | 0:
 | | | | poetry:
 | | | | | 0:
 | | | | | | honor:
 | | | | | | | 0: 0
 | | | | | | | 1: 1
 | | | | | |
 | | | | |
 | | | | | 1:
 | | | | | | honor:
 | | | | | | | 0: 1
 | | | | | | | 1: 0
 | | | | | |
 | | | | |
 | | | |
 | | |
 | | | 1: 0
 | |
 |
 | 1:
 | | romulan:
 | | | 0: 1
 | | | 1: 0
 | |
 |
```

You could play around with the `.replace()` calls to get it just right.

Comment: Very Nice and simple to use

Answer (score 5):

This will output exactly what you want.

```
# If you are not using Python 3
from __future__ import print_function

tree = {'wesley': {'1': {'romulan': {'1': '0', '0': '1'}}, '0': {'romulan': {'1': '0', '0': {'poetry': {'1': {'honor': {'1': '0', '0': '1'}}, '0': {'honor': {'1': '1', '0': '0'}}}}}}}}

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def go(dic, last_key, current_level):
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if is_number(key):
            for i in range(current_level - 1):
                print("| ", end="")

            print(last_key, "= ", end="")
            print(key, ": ", end="")
        else:
            if current_level > 0:
                print("")

            current_level = current_level + 1

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            go(value, key, current_level)
        else:
            print(value)

go(tree, None, 0)
```

Output:

```
wesley = 1 :
| romulan = 1 : 0
| romulan = 0 : 1
wesley = 0 :
| romulan = 1 : 0
| romulan = 0 :
| | poetry = 1 :
| | | honor = 1 : 0
| | | honor = 0 : 1
| | poetry = 0 :
| | | honor = 1 : 1
| | | honor = 0 : 0
```